# Using a Variable/Token for Config Directories to Get Site Root Path

Tags: tokens, configuration, settings, directory

I am using Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 4.7.12.

When setting the Directories for CiviCRM...

I know you can use [civicrm.files] and [civicrm.root] to get file system paths. However, I have my extensions, custom templates and custom php in the root of my web server.

Is there a token or variable that I can set that will point CiviCRM to the root directory of my site?

For example I could have the following for the "Custom Template Directory":
[site.root]/CustomTemplates

Note: There is a Paths.php file that defines a Paths class that contains cms.root. However, when using that in the directories settings it tells me that the path cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at issue [CRM-19371](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19371). It a small bug and fixed in CiviCrm 4.7.13. I fixed my 4.7.12 installation by using [this patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9047/files).